# compiler timeouts while pushing to heroku - python, django

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm getting compiler timeouts while pushing to heroku

I use 
APP : python + django.
OS : Mac Lion

INSTALLED_APPS  IS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.humanize',   # 4000 -> 4,000
'django.contrib.admin',
'gunicorn',
'kombu.transport.django',
'djcelery',
'django_facebook',
'google_analytics',
'tagging',
'registration',
'social_auth',
'cms',
'mptt',
'menus',
'south',
'sekizai', 
'social_auth',
's3_folder_storage',
'krstyle',   # my app
'template_debug',
)
```

It seems that this is somewhat related to my django file, since if i run git push heroku master

Here is the log :

```
       Cleaning up...
 -----> Collecting static files
/app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in spawn': command='/app/slug-compiler/lib/../buildpacks/python/bin/compile /tmp/build_24on8vwgty6ka /app/tmp/repo.git/.cache' exit_status=0 out='' at=timeout elapsed=195.8211374282837 (Utils::TimeoutError)
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:51:in `loop'
....
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:58:in `timeout'
from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:101:in `rescue in timeout'
...
from /app/slug-compiler/bin/slugc:66:in `<main>'
!     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Python/django app

To git@heroku.com:cryptic-wave-9874.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```